# Strchr and strrchr returning same result

Tags: c, string, pointers, string.h, c-str

For some reason, whether I try `strchr` or `strrchr`, I get the same value returned. I have no idea why.

Here is the segment of code giving me trouble:

```
      printf("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input):\n");
      fgets(input, 50, stdin);
      char *name = strrchr(input, ',');
      if(name)
      {
         printf("%s", name);
      }
```

The input is `Jane Austen, 6`, and I am trying to separate it into two strings: one before the comma and one after the comma. However, my use of `strrchr(input, ',');` or `strchr(input, ',');` seems pointless, as my output is ALWAYS `, 6`. Can someone explain why?

Comment: If there's only one comma in the string, then that same comma is found whether you are looking for the "first" or the "last" of that character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `strtok` instead:

```
char *name = strtok(input, ",");
char *value = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

Comment: I think this works, thank you. I mistakenly thought that the only difference between strchr and strrchr was that one started from index 0 and the other started at index length - 1.

Comment: That _is_ the only difference - `strchr` starts at index 0 and goes forward, and `strrchr` starts at `strlen(s) - 1` and goes backwards. As @SteveFriedl points out, if you only have one `,` then these two will find the same result. They only really give you the position of the character but won't split the string for you - `strtok` does and that makes it more useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages provide a string function split that takes a string or regular expression and splits the string into a list of substrings separated by the delimiter (python, ruby, perl). It is not too difficult to construct such a split function, especially if you just split on a single character.

```
char** split(char* string, char delim);
```

You will also want a string join function, and a function to cleanup the allocated space.

```
char* split_join(char** splitray, char* buffer);
void split_free(char** splitray);
```

Comment: wouldn't the split function just be `strtok`?

Comment: read about split in python. strtok separates a string into two parts (destructively).